# How to clean markers Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need help to place markers and cash them eliminated as they have asked me a similar application to Uber, the problem is that while I move the car stays visible in the previous position and I don't know how to remove it and put the new brand to give the effect of movement.

My reference:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex?hl=es-419

My Code:

```
function initMap() {
    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: "Styled Map" });

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.302286, -99.192976),
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        mapOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
    setInterval(function() { setMarkers(map); }, 5000);
}

var LAC1 = [
    19.3027874, 19.302775, 19.302708, 19.302647, 19.302601, 19.302537,
    19.302513, 19.302472, 19.302444, 19.302397, 19.302353, 19.302332,
    19.302298, 19.302283, 19.302265, 19.302270, 19.302190, 19.302186,
    19.302198, 19.302268, 19.302334, 19.302449, 19.302506, 19.302659,
    19.302870, 19.303052, 19.303217
];
var LC1 = [
    -99.1872615, -99.187810, -99.188320, -99.188846, -99.189252, -99.189853,
    -99.190115, -99.190555, -99.190870, -99.191272, -99.191633, -99.191913,
    -99.192264, -99.192547, -99.192755, -99.192918, -99.193718, -99.194205,
    -99.194586, -99.195342, -99.195847, -99.196445, -99.196624, -99.197140,
    -99.197661, -99.198034, -99.198320
];
var conT = 0;

function setMarkers(map) {
    if (conT < 27) {
        var camiones = [
            ['Camion 1', LAC1[conT], LC1[conT], 1]
        ];
        conT = conT + 1;
    } else {
        conT = null;
        conT = 0;
    }
    var image = {
        url: 'camion.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(70, 30) // scaled size
    };
    var shape = {
        coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1]
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < camiones.length; i++) {

        var camionT = camiones[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: camionT[1], lng: camionT[2] },
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            title: camionT[0],
            zIndex: camionT[3]
        });
    }
}
```

[image: example image]

Comment: duplicate of [Delete google maps marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013032/delete-google-maps-marker)

Comment: duplicate of [Remove the previous marker and add marker in the updated lat lng](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679672/remove-the-previous-marker-and-add-marker-in-the-updated-lat-lng)

Comment: duplicate of [How can I get a single marker to update it's position as the user moves?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870667/how-can-i-get-a-single-marker-to-update-its-position-as-the-user-moves)

Answer (score 1):

First, add your markers to an array, while you add them to the map (inside setMarkers). Then use this:

```
 function setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }

setMapOnAll(null);
```

Call it every time before setMarkers inside the interval.

Afterwards you could go further and remove only the ones that have really moved. (Through analysis of the markers in the array and the new markers)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one marker and you want to update its position, only create it once, then move it.

```
// if marker doesn't exist, create it
if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: camionT[1],
      lng: camionT[2]
    },
    map: map,
    title: camionT[0],
    zIndex: camionT[3]
  });
} else {
// if marker already exists, move it
  marker.setPosition({
    lat: camionT[1],
    lng: camionT[2]
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rq7585ho/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.302286, -99.192976),
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOptions);
  setInterval(function() {
    setMarkers(map);
  }, 5000);
}

var LAC1 = [
  19.3027874, 19.302775, 19.302708, 19.302647, 19.302601, 19.302537,
  19.302513, 19.302472, 19.302444, 19.302397, 19.302353, 19.302332,
  19.302298, 19.302283, 19.302265, 19.302270, 19.302190, 19.302186,
  19.302198, 19.302268, 19.302334, 19.302449, 19.302506, 19.302659,
  19.302870, 19.303052, 19.303217
];
var LC1 = [-99.1872615, -99.187810, -99.188320, -99.188846, -99.189252, -99.189853, -99.190115, -99.190555, -99.190870, -99.191272, -99.191633, -99.191913, -99.192264, -99.192547, -99.192755, -99.192918, -99.193718, -99.194205, -99.194586, -99.195342, -99.195847, -99.196445, -99.196624, -99.197140, -99.197661, -99.198034, -99.198320];
var conT = 0;
var marker;

function setMarkers(map) {
  if (conT < 27) {
    var camiones = [
      ['Camion 1', LAC1[conT], LC1[conT], 1]
    ];
    conT = conT + 1;
  } else {
    conT = null;
    conT = 0;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < camiones.length; i++) {

    var camionT = camiones[i];
    if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: camionT[1],
          lng: camionT[2]
        },
        map: map,
        title: camionT[0],
        zIndex: camionT[3]
      });
    } else {
      marker.setPosition({
        lat: camionT[1],
        lng: camionT[2]
      });
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```